# textToBePresentInElement() is not working with exact text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to locate and wait for an element with the text "Total " with space after "Total". The locator I've used is:

```
//td[./text()='Total ']
```

The wait I've implemented for it is:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element,"Total "));
```

I'm getting `TimeOutException`. If I remove the space after the text "**Total**". it's working. The wait implementation now is:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, "Total"));
```

Why the condition `textToBePresentInElement` is not working with the exact text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the answer in the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java)

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> textToBePresentInElement(final WebElement element, final String text) {
    //...
    String elementText = element.getText();
    return elementText.contains(text);
    //...
}
```

The method get the text using `element.getText();`, which means the text returned [as rendered by the browser](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#get-element-text), i.e. without trailing space

> The Get Element Text command intends to return an element’s text “as
>   rendered”...

When you use the text `"Total "` you are basically check in the expected condition if

```
"Total".contains("Total ");
```

Which is `false`, but without the trailing space it works.